External monitor on a Macbook Pro 14" goes into low power mode after a few minutes
My 2023 14-inch MacBook Pro with an Apple M3 Pro chip, all updates applied, is connected to two Dell screens: Dell S2721DGF (screen 1) and Dell S2725DS (screen 2). Screen 1 is connected via an HDMI cable, and screen 2 is connected via an Apple USB-C to HDMI connector. Screen 2 will go into standby mode after a few minutes, no matter what I am doing at the time.
I have tried various resolutions and refresh rates to no avail.
When I swap screens 1 and 2 around, screen 2 shows the same behaviour. I connected the screens to a Windows laptop in the same configuration. The screen connected via USB-C to HDMI does not go into a low-power state.
I checked https://support.apple.com/en-gb/101571, and it seems it should work unless the Thunderbolt to HDMI connector isn't supported?

Two external displays Supports two displays in any one of these
configurations:
Two displays up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt
One display up to 6K at 60 Hz over Thunderbolt, and one display up to
4K at 144 Hz over HDMI

What could the issue be?

The problem was solved by using a Volkano USB-C to HDMI connector. The Apple connector worked with two external screens and a Windows laptop, so I assume the issue is not a faulty adapter but a compatibility issue.
